# Heroku Error `secret_key_base` for production environment must be a type of String`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, credentials

When I put $git push heroku master, I got an argument error:

remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        ArgumentError: `secret_key_base` for production environment must be a type of String
`remote:        /tmp/build_19076210a01025325310b08d032af424/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:583:in`validate_secret_key_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_19076210a01025325310b08d032af424/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:432:in `secret_key_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_19076210a01025325310b08d032af424/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:176:in`key_generator'
remote:        /tmp/build_19076210a01025325310b08d032af424/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:205:in `message_verifier'
.......................

My Rails version is 5.2 and which has new encrypt system filed in config/credentials.yml.enc. I guess this configuration makes this heroku error.

No one has this question and describe how to solve this error.

Could you please help me how to solve this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://waiyanyoon.com/deploying-rails-5-2-applications-with-encrypted-credentials-using-capistrano/

also before pushing to heroku try to compile assets in PRODUCTION mode locally to see if everything works.